# wikijs Error: Database Initialization Error: create table "migrations"

Tags: postgresql, wiki.js

I am in the process of installing wikijs on CentoOS7.9

I did:

```
download and install node-v16.9.1-linux-x64 
yum install postgresql15-server
yum install postgresql15-contrib
/usr/pgsql-15/bin/postgresql-15-setup initdb
```

When I start the wikijs I get:

```
[root@]# node server
Loading configuration from /usr/local/wiki/config.yml... OK
2023-03-22T14:04:45.112Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2023-03-22T14:04:45.114Z [MASTER] info: = Wiki.js 2.5.298 =====================
2023-03-22T14:04:45.115Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2023-03-22T14:04:45.115Z [MASTER] info: Initializing...
2023-03-22T14:04:45.764Z [MASTER] info: Using database driver pg for postgres [ OK ]
2023-03-22T14:04:45.775Z [MASTER] info: Connecting to database...
2023-03-22T14:04:45.803Z [MASTER] info: Database Connection Successful [ OK ]
2023-03-22T14:04:45.820Z [MASTER] error: Database Initialization Error: create table "migrations" ("id" serial primary key, "name" varchar(255), "batch" integer, "migration_time" timestamptz) - permission denied for schema public
```

What can cause this issue?

Comment: Does the user have the necessary privilledges to create tables in public?

Comment: I run: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE wiki TO wikijs; Is it enough?

Comment: I also run and did not help:postgres=# GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public to wikijs;
postgres=# GRANT ALL ON DATABASE wiki TO wikijs;
postgres=# GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO wikijs;

Comment: I got the same problem trying to migrate my wiki from docker containers to a baremetal installation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command that solve the problem for me :
ALTER DATABASE wiki OWNER TO wikijs;

Comment: If anyone wants to elaborate an better answer... this [article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/error-permission-denied-schema-public/) explain why change owner is a good solution